# How to remove horizontal whitespace between matplotlib subplots with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have the following code and I am trying to remove the space between the 3 subplots.
I have tried both `gridspec.GridSpec` and `fig.subplots_adjust` and both fail.

The individual colorbars should be there as they are now.

Any idea?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# random data
x1 = np.random.rand(1,10)
x2 = np.random.rand(1,10)
x3 = np.random.rand(1,10)

nrow, ncol = 3, 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol, figsize=(12,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01, hspace=0.01)
axes = axes.flatten()

cmaps = ['Greens_r', 'Reds', 'jet']
x_all = [x1,x2,x3]

for i in range(3):
        im = axes[i].imshow(x_all[i], cmap=cmaps[i])
        #plt.colorbar(im, ax=axes[i])

        axes[i].set_xticklabels([])
        axes[i].set_yticklabels([]) 
        axes[i].set_xticks([])
        axes[i].set_yticks([])
        
        #Make an axis for the colorbar on the right side
        divider = make_axes_locatable(axes[i])
        cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
        fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep the pixels square? If not, then you could use `aspect="auto"` in the call to `imshow`.

Comment: First, suggest use `inset_axes` for the colorbar, rather than the old toolkit.  Second, you can't really do this easily.  The best way to reduce the whitespace is to adjust the aspect ratio of your figure

Comment: @DavidG indeed this solves the problem. But what if i want to keep the pixels square?

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks for the tip. I was not aware of this. I will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first draw you figure as is and then adjust the position of the top and bottom axes relative to the middle one by moving them by the amount of the gap between them minus a certain `space`. This is easiest if you follow Jody's advise to use `inset_axes`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mt
import numpy as np

# random data
np.random.seed(42)
x_all = (np.random.rand(1,10), np.random.rand(1,10), np.random.rand(1,10))
cmaps = ['Greens_r', 'Reds', 'jet']

space = 0.01
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(12,6))

for ax, x, cmap in zip(axes, x_all, cmaps):
        ax.axis('off')
        im = ax.imshow(x, cmap=cmap)
        cax = ax.inset_axes([1 + space, 0, 0.05, 1])
        fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, cax=cax)

fig.canvas.draw()
t = mt.Affine2D().translate(0, axes[1].get_position().y1 - axes[0].get_position().y0 + space)
axes[0].set_position(mt.TransformedBbox(axes[0].get_position(), t))
t = mt.Affine2D().translate(0, axes[1].get_position().y0 - axes[2].get_position().y1 - space)
axes[2].set_position(mt.TransformedBbox(axes[2].get_position(), t))
```

[image]